# Creat React App: Adding scss

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Looking for a little explanation.

I added .scss support to my create-react-app and every thing works (like in docs: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc).

There is these lines with plus sign:

```
"scripts": {
+    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
+    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
```

My first question is what first src/ and second src/ stands for?
In this approach it creates .css file next to .scss. My second question is how to make one .css, no matter how many .scss files I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first and second `/src` are the paths of the input and output, something like source and destination of your files, you only want to read .scss files inside your `/src` folders and the result is built inside that same `/src` folder.
2. You can prepend an underscore(_) to your SCSS files and this will tell SASS that those files will have no file output when compiled, so if for example you have a file named `navBar.scss` you should change it to `_navbar.scss`. Make sure you are importing those files from some other .scss file that doesn't have an underscore though, otherwise the compiler task will do nothing with those files.

To import the files you don't have to specify the underscore, but you do have to put the exact route of the files for example to import your _navbar.scss:

```
@import 'route/to/components/navbar/navbar'
```

Answer (score 0):

The first src/ is where it is reading files from, then -o designates output, and the second src/ is the output directory, which is why it is creating the new files in the same location as the source files.

For single file output try `node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/outputfile.css`